# Error while removing two nodes in doubly linked list in java

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

I have problems in doubly LinkedList and I am not using a tail I instead use a current pointer. When I use the tail I don't find problem but when I use a current pointer I get an error and I can not solve it. It occurs when I remove a node. My program is working but I can not remove the next node.
This is the error message:

**This the class DNode**

```
public class DNode<T> { 
 T data;
 DNode<T> next;
DNode<T> prev;
public DNode(T e){
 data = e;
    next = prev = null;
}
```

**This class DoubleLinkedList**

```
public class DoubleLinkedList<T> {

DNode<T> head;
DNode<T> current;
int size = 0;
public DoubleLinkedList() {
    head = current = null;
}
public void Insert(T e) {
    DNode<T> tmp = new DNode(e);
    if (size == 0) {
        head = current = tmp;
    } else {
        tmp.next = current.next;
        tmp.prev = current;
        current.next = tmp;
        current = tmp;

    }
    size++;
}

public void remove() {
    if (head == current) {
        if (current.next == null) {
            head = current = null;
        } else {
            current.next.prev = null;
            head = current.next;
            current.next = null;
            current = head;
        }
    } else {
        DNode<T> tmp = current.next;

        current.prev.next = tmp;
        if (tmp != null) {
            tmp.prev = current;
        }
        current.next = current.prev = null;
        current = tmp;
    }

    size--;

}
```

**The main calss**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
DoubleLinkedList<String> d = new DoubleLinkedList();


  d.Insert("jon");
    d.Insert("jack");
    d.Insert("mohammed");
    d.remove();
    d.remove();// here my problem
 }
```

The line with the comment is where I get an error.

Comment: And what **is** the problem?

Comment: when add d.remove(); second time I can not delete if find the massage error

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at assignment1.DoubleLinkedList.remove(DoubleLinkedList.java:91)//if I click will be go to  DNode<T> tmp = current.next;
 at assignment1.Assignment1.main(Assignment1.java:43)// and here to  d.remove(); the second one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I see this before and try to solve but I can't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the else part of your remove function, you assign current to tmp. When you say `current = tmp;` tmp could be null. So the next time when the remove is called, if it enters the else clause(which it would in your case) current will be null, and `current.next` gives the null pointer exception.

**EDIT** :
This would be a possible suggestion :

```
/*Deletes the last node in the list*/
public void remove() {
  if(head == null || size == 0) return; // Empty list
  if(head == current || size ==1){    // List with only one node
    head = null;
    current = null;
    size--;
    return;
  }
  DNode<T> previous = current.prev;
  previous.next = current.next;
  current.prev = null;
  current = previous;
    size--;
}
```

Comment: I understand you but how can I fix

Comment: Added a remove function to my answer